# MongoDB target machine actively refused it

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel-5

I having a problem when trying to connect mongodb database in laravel 5. I'm using  [jenssegers/laravel-mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/Laravel-MongoDB#installation) .

I have found like two other persons who are having that same issue in some forums, but there was no solution posted until recent.

I'm trying many solution but not working .
 Does anybody have more info on that?

Config.php

```
 'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mongodb'),
        'mongodb' => [
            'driver'    => 'mongodb',
            'host'      => 'localhost',
            'port'      =>env('DB_PORT', 27017),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'test'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'options'  => array('db' => 'admin')
        ],
```

config/app.php

```
   Jenssegers\Mongodb\MongodbServiceProvider::class,
```

bootstrap/app.php

```
$app->register('Jenssegers\Mongodb\MongodbServiceProvider');
```

Controller.php

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Model as Eloquent;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Testmongo extends Eloquent
{
    protected $collection = 'mongodb';



    public function Users(){
        MongoLog::setModule(MongoLog::ALL);
MongoLog::setLevel(MongoLog::ALL);
MongoLog::setCallback('print_mongo_log');
function print_mongo_log($a, $b, $c) { echo $c, "\n"; }
/*
   $users = DB::collection('users')->get();
print_r($users);
*/      
    }

}
```

Pleas help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my fall. Problem solved with changing in database file

```
'mongodb' => [
            'name'       => 'mongodb',
            'driver'     => 'mongodb',
            'host'       => '127.0.0.1',
            'database'   => 'products',
        ],
```

Using this configuration.